# How to covert Java into Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

```
final EditText etAge = (EditText()) findViewById(R.id.etAge)
```

I need to convert this into Kotlin, and I don't know a way to convert it easily.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html

Comment: That isn't even valid Java

Comment: `Val yourEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etAge)` and `EditText()` isn’t valid though. Or; `val yourEditText = findViewById(R.id.etAge) as EditText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using android studio, go to Code => Convert Java File to Kotlin File, or just paste into a kotlin file

Answer (score 1):

Press

**Control + Alt + Shift + K** (windows) and

**Option + Command + Shift + K** (Mac)

while the java file opened

Answer (score 0):

Press key combination `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K` from your Java file or go to **`Code>>Convert Java File to Kotlin File`**. And converted Kotlin file will replace your Java file and Android Studio may ask you to configure Kotlin as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with kotlin extensions and depending on the context you wouldn't even need to use `findViewById` but can directly access the 'EditText` view via it's id.